# Next.js Loads <script> tags but it doesn't execute them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm integrating an existing React app into Next.js for mainly SEO features.

i pasted the css files links inside the `<Header>` tag in `Next.js` and they seem to work just fine. when i tried to do the same with the javascript files using the `<script>` tag, it doesn't execute the code inside those scripts. but i can see them loaded with `http 200` in the chrome dev tools.

I tried using a library called `Loadjs` from `npm` to load the scripts inside `componentDidMount` but i got the exact same result as using `<script>` tag.

is there a proper way to do such simple thing in `Next.js` that i'm not aware of ?

Here's the code included in the `pages/index.js` file.

```
  import React from "react"
  import Head from 'next/head'
  import MyAwesomeComponent from "../components/mycomponent.js"
  export default () => (
    <div>
      <Head>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/chatwidget.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/download.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin@3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/libs/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/scripts/chatHead.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/libs/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
      </Head>

      <MyAwesomeComponent /> {/* a simple React component that returns  : <p>Hello World </p>*/}
    </div>
  )
```

---

Sorry for the late answer.
it turned out that all the `scripts` i linked missed one script that would actually run the `functions` for each action.

Comment: Have you tried to input the script tags in a custom document.Check this page for more info how to create a custom document tag in nextjs.https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-document

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Can you share please?

Comment: Hey @Sleek, check if my answer works for you

Comment: @Sleek the scripts was working but i was not calling any functions out of them, so it didn't seem like they were functional.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This works to me:

Create a folder for your static files:

`<root>/public/static/script.js`

in your index.js at `<root>/pages/index.js`

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import MyAwesomeComponent from '../components/mycomponent';

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script.js"></script>
    </Head>
    <MyAwesomeComponent />
  </div>
)
```

Note that `static` is the name I used in this example, it's not a requirement, it would work with any other folder name.

Comment: Does this work in dev environment ? Cause i tried this and seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: Same here. Trying to find a solution that hot reloads. Any progress @Shadab?

Comment: Yep, tested locally few years ago :), which nextjs version are you using guys?

Comment: Hi @AndreVitorio I have added an answer to this have a look at it. It is working for me in dev environment.

Comment: You got the right idea, but I think you meant to put the script in `/public` not `/static`

Comment: working dev and production envs

Comment: @MuhammedMoussa How exactly did you get it working? Doesn't work for me

Comment: @YaddyVirus , i followed the answer, also working with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: @MuhammedMoussa I did the same but in my case the script didn't even load initially. Could you share a snippet?

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the path issue, it was using an example that was working with Next.js 6, but not with the latest versions. (10+)

Answer (score 34):

With the below approach you can easily put a script file's **raw script text** into a generated Next.js HTML page's `<head>` without screwing around with character escaping, formatting and general pretending that we aren't actually just building an HTML page in the end anyways.

There are many use cases you may want a script to run without going to network. Ex: 3rd party scripts, monitoring / analytics scripts that expect to be in the `<head>` without a separate network load. Many of these come minified, mangled, you-name-it and are just supposed to be copy, paste, move on with life.

Next.js makes this very hard pretending that everything with web development is magically React and Webpack all the time now (I wish right?)

The best developer experience way I've found is to do this:

**_document.js**

```
...
<Head>
  <script type="text/javascript" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: process.env.rawJsFromFile }}></script>
</Head>
...
```

**next.config.js**

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/next-server/server/config.ts#L33

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    rawJsFromFile: fs.readFileSync('./rawJsFromFile.js').toString()
  }
}
```

**rawJsFromFile.js**

```
alert('Freedom!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
// and other 3rd party script junk, heck even minified JS is fine too if you need
```

Hope this saves someone from hours of frustration that I endured coming up with this...

Comment: Thank you John.. this worked perfectly for it. I had already tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but webpack was modifying the included js. This is the perfect way to include tracking js without any complaints from ts, without loading it as a separate script, and without the risk of js being modified. Every thankful!

Comment: This is the correct answer if you're including 3rd party scripts with inline code. \o/

Comment: based on that path... where do I put the rawJsFromFile.js file?

Answer (score 24):

You can also run js code this

```html
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
                      let a = 1;
                      functionCall();
                  `,
            }}
          ></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

With Next.js v11 and onward, you can use the Next component `Script`

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11#script-optimization

```
<Script
  src="..."
  strategy="beforeInteractive"
/>
```

Comment: I have used it. It is not loading google analytics code. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: same here when i inspect page i cannot see google analytics loaded, in returned html it is there but not executing. window.gtag is undefined

Comment: Apparently the Next Script does not work when in the Next Head component, putting it into any other component works.

Answer (score 4):

May this helps you [Nextjs public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436021/nextjs-public-folder)

Move your static folder into public folder in your root directory

```
export default () => (
    <div>
      <Head>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/chatwidget.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/download.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
        ...
      </Head>

      <MyAwesomeComponent /> 
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried and it worked for me.
I used two files `entry-script.js` and  `main-script.js`. I put these like this
`<root>/static/entry-script.js`  and  `<root>/static/main-script.js`
The content of `entry-script.js` is below.

```
(function (d, t) {
  t = d.createElement("script");
  t.setAttribute("src", "/static/main-script.js");
  d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t);
})(document);
```

and the main logic is in the file `main-script.js`.
In the file `_doucment.js` of NextJS I included my file `entry-script.js` in body like below

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="/static/entry-script.js"
          ></script>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article elaborating on this question, hopefully it comes in handy:

https://www.devtwins.com/blog/how-to-add-a-third-party-script-to-a-nextjs-website

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30370210)

Comment: @Zach White, I took a look at the article (helpful!) and I see you are now recommending Next's custom <Script> component, however, using this in combination with Next's <Head></Head> fails to execute the script. Wondering if you have knowledge here. I'm implementing an inline script for analytics that needs dynamic elements passed in.

Comment: Agreed. @Zach White you might want to elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Or if you want to try another way to import Js file like I did

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        import("../styles/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
    }, []);
    return <></>
};
```

Comment: That question was before react hooks existed :)