# Nextjs public folder

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Where is the **public** folder for a nextjs project?

I mean, is there somewhere where I can put `favicon.png`, google site verification, `manifest.json`, `robots.txt`, etc. ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Next.js has a `public/` folder

Create stuff like `public/favicon.png`, `public/robots.txt` and that's all you need.

And put your `static` folder inside `public` to keep your assets in it with all assets bundling and compressing benefits.

```
/public
    /static
        /images
        /css
        /fonts
    robots.txt
    manifest.json
```

[Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

Comment: It is important to note that the `public` directory should be in the root directory even if you are using the `src` directory.

Comment: I can't able to access my image :- `<img src="/assets/images/my-image.png" alt="my image" />` how to access public folder inside folder image in next js ?

Comment: Note that for generated text files, you can use a Route Handler: `app/rss.xml/route.ts` where "rss.xml" is a folder name. For the end user, it will look like a file.
For private files, you can also use a Route Handler, I've documented how to stream files from there: https://www.ericburel.tech/blog/nextjs-stream-files

Answer (score 26):

For web process anything in /public is at the url so easy.  However, if you are trying to access the files on the server side of nextjs (either in one of the static async SSR, or as an API call) - as the paths there seem to need to be absolute paths.  To access that you need to capture the running directory at build time, and then access it.

next.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
        PROJECT_ROOT: __dirname
    }
}
```

And a helper for getting server side paths:

```js
import path from 'path'
import getConfig from 'next/config'

const serverPath = (staticFilePath: string) => {
  return path.join(getConfig().serverRuntimeConfig.PROJECT_ROOT, staticFilePath)
}

export default serverPath
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution. On localhost, it throws this error when I start the server.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
On subsequent API calls, it works as expected and my font loads correctly. 

When I deploy to production then it crashes every time 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/path0/public/Roboto-Regular.ttf

Do you have any suggestion here?

Comment: @user3884753 - Hmm, looks like you are hosting on vercel, I'm not super familiar with how they work as a host personally.  I'd double check the path, and maybe contact your server host support as that seems like an issue with pathing and the native os behavior (which they may be able to help with)

Comment: @user3884753 did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Sliffcak Instead of `serverRuntimeConfig`, place `PROJECT_ROOT` inside `env` in the next config, and default it to empty string when using it in the code

Answer (score 21):

for Next.js 9:
Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called `public` in the root directory. Files inside `public` can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (`/`).

For example, if you add an image to `public/my-image.png`, the following code will access the image:

```
function MyImage() {
  return <img src="/my-image.png" alt="my image" />
}

export default MyImage
```

refrence: [enter link description here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

Answer (score 10):

**Static file serving (e.g.: images)**

create a folder called `static` in your project root directory. From your code you can then reference those files with `/static/` URLs:

```
export default () => <img src="/static/my-image.png" alt="my image" />
```

***Note***: Don't name the static directory anything else. The name is required and is the only directory that Next.js uses for serving static assets.

for more read [Docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#static-file-serving-eg-images)

Comment: As of May 1, 2019, public folder support has been added in addition to the static folder. See this PR https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/7213

Answer (score 7):

The static directory has been deprecated in favor of the public directory.
https://err.sh/zeit/next.js/static-dir-deprecated

create a folder called public in your project root directory. From your code you can then reference those files with URLs:

```
export default () => <img src="/my-image.png" alt="my image" />
```

Comment: This only works for me when running next dev. When I do next build and deploy, I get a 404

Comment: In my situation, when using the `next build` command, the `public` folder is not included. Therefore, if you plan on deploying the `.next` folder, make sure to also copy the `public` folder to the deployment machine/docker.

Answer (score 3):

Next can use a /public folder. Just create one if you don't have it. I have my small project set up as:

```
project-root
    /public
        /blog-images
        /fonts
        favicon.ico
        etc.png
    /src
        /pages
        /components
        /styles
            globals.css
        /utils
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a public folder in the root of your project. NextJS would automatically grab the website's static content from the folder.

If an image is in `public` folder such that Image URL is: `projectRoot/public/myImg.jpg` then you can access it inside your JSX or TSX files by using `/myImg.jpg`

For more information check out the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/226) you could serve static files server side, just like this ([source](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/root-static-files/server.js)):

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
const { join } = require('path')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const rootStaticFiles = ['/robots.txt', '/sitemap.xml', '/favicon.ico']
    if (rootStaticFiles.indexOf(parsedUrl.pathname) > -1) {
      const path = join(__dirname, 'static', parsedUrl.pathname)
      app.serveStatic(req, res, path)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

the /public folder. You
need to restart the website after adding files to this folder

Answer (score 0):

Where is the public folder for a nextjs project?

Answer: into the root directory of the project, you create `public` folder and put `favicon.png` into this.

You can reference the sample at https://github.com/dotuan9x/nextjs-boilerplate. I already use this for my website https://nghesachnoi.com and reality https://nghesachnoi.com/favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

You can place image inside public folder.

after that using `import Head from "next/head"` you can place `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="relative path in public folder"/>`