# Next 11 and adding Script tags not working. No scripts are rendered

Tags: next.js

I added my google tag manager to **_app.js** file, and its not showing. None of the scripts I am loading via the new "Script" tag are working.

```
  <Head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <Script
      src={`https://cdn.somelink.coom/${process.env.COOKIE_KEY}/block.js`}
      strategy="beforeInteractive"
    />
    <Script
      src="https://cdn.somelink.com/scripttemplates/stub.js"
      strategy="beforeInteractive"
    />
    <Script
      src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GOOGLE_KEY}`}
      strategy="afterInteractive"
    />
```

These are not working. Nothing is downloaded in the network tab etc. Nothing shows up on the page. Any thoughts?

Reminder: this is in the **_app.js** file.

Note: My pages are static generated.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436021/nextjs-public-folder

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> `next/script` should not be wrapped in `next/head`

Ref.: [Script Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script)

Do something like this:

```
import Script from "next/script";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
  <>
    <Script
      id="scriptAfterInteractive"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"
    />
    {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-​spreading */}
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: so, the only thing different here is you moved it out of the <Head tag?

Comment: Wow, the docs really should stress that more. Current version of the docs in April 2022 just says "It enables developers to set the loading priority of third-party scripts anywhere in their application, outside next/head, saving developer time..." Looks like it's a requirement though.

Comment: Looks like there's also some issues with wrapping it in the `Html` Next component too? If you're having difficulties with this, try burying the Script somewhere in a random component and see if it works, then work up from there.

Comment: I'm getting a "Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened" when I do this. I have the `strategy="beforeInteractive"` and have tried all of the other kinds of strategy values as well. The web worker strategy is the only one that doesn't throw an error but still doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding beforeInteractive strategy "only works inside _document.js and is designed to load scripts that are needed by the entire site" - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#:~:text=This%20strategy%20only%20works%20inside%20_document.js%20and%20is%20designed%20to%20load%20scripts%20that%20are%20needed%20by%20the%20entire%20site

Comment: @AhmadM.Hawwash Yeah, it was updated in the last version. If you need to use that strategy in your pages, then you now need to do this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/0441f816a668fdfef19e1b35a6fc7333e0bdcf87/test/integration/script-loader/base/pages/page1.js -- note that this is unstable right now and may change in future.

Comment: @yankeedoodle Adding `defer={false}` should fix the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252819/embedding-external-script-into-next-js-application.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the requirement that `Script` (next/script) not be wrapped in `Head` (next/head), it should also **not** be placed within a custom `_document.tsx` unless you are **not** passing `strategy="beforeInteractive"` [as mentioned in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#beforeinteractive).

I was unable to load a Cloudflare analytics script when placing it in `_document.tsx`, but it loaded successfully as a sibling to `Component` in `_app.tsx`.

Comment: Next.js `v12.1` allowed adding to `_document.js`, but from `v12.2` it does not. Only `beforeInteractive` supports in document.