# How to lazy load Facebook Chat into Next.js to avoid slow down?

Tags: next.js, facebook-messenger, google-pagespeed

Got this from Google Page Speed:

> [image]

Though I did put loading code in `_document.tsx` into a `setTimeout` with 3s timing.

```js
<div id="fb-customer-chat" className="fb-customerchat"></div>
<Script strategy="lazyOnload" id="facebook-chat">
    {`
        var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
        chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "103015511335105");
        chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");
  
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v12.0'
          });
        };
  
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        `}
</Script>
```

How should I load FB Messanger, to avoid slow down page?

Coming from this approach anyway: [How to add Facebook chat messenger to Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463559/how-to-add-facebook-chat-messenger-to-next-js)