# Script Component does not work in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm working in Tiny Editor, it's necessary to define a key for the editor, following the documentation I can consult this key through the tag <script src = 'address', that's how it works, but when joining the Script component of the next .js (< Script src = 'address') I can't communicate with tiny anymore, has anyone been through this?

```
# It works
<script src='address' />

# Does not work
<Script src='address' />
```

doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Comment: Maybe because next.js is for React and React recognises html if beginning with lowercase. React Components begin with uppercase. Maybe it thinks jts a react component and not a script tag and the  React component 'Script' doesn't exist .

Comment: Can you show us the full code for the component where you're using `next/script`? Have you tried using `strategy="beforeInteractive"`?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/68059559/11613622?

Answer (score 2):

- If `Script` component is inside `<Head>` component, use it outside `<Head>`
- Try in a different browser. It might be browser-specific issue
- default value for the strategy prop is `afterInteractive`. with this, script is fetched and executed after the page is interactive. Use `beforeInteractive` for critical scripts that need to be fetched and executed before the page is interactive.
- use onError props for debugging.

  ```
   onError={(e) => {
          console.error('Script failed to load', e)
        }}
  ```