# Embedding external script into Next.js application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I've been trying to embed an external JavaScript source into my Next.js application and keep receiving following error:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
> into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
> it is explicitly opened.

The code I am trying to use can be found [here](https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/CMA-CGM-TROCADERO-IMO-9839167-MMSI-228402900) - The map with the vessel has an option to embed it. So far the component that generates this error looks like this:

```
<div className={styles['container']}>
    <Script type="text/javascript">
        var width="100%";var height="400"; var mmsi=228402900;
    </Script>
    <Script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://www.vesselfinder.com/aismap.js">
    </Script>
</div>
```

If I copy the embed code into CodePen it works just fine - [link to my codepen with the embedded map here](https://codepen.io/marprivoznik/pen/MWQJKwv).

Does somebody know what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue occurs because the external script is being loaded asynchronously by `next/script`, thus ignoring the `document.write()` call present in the script.

From [`Document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write#notes) MDN documentation:

> **Note:** Using `document.write()` in [deferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) or [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) scripts will
> be ignored and you'll get a message like "A call to `document.write()`
> from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored" in the
> error console.

You'll need to set the [`Script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) strategy to `beforeInteractive` so the script is added to `<head>`, and explicitly set the `defer` property to `false` to prevent the script from being loaded asynchronously.

```js
<Script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://www.vesselfinder.com/aismap.js"
    strategy="beforeInteractive"
    defer={false}
></Script>
```

Comment: This also means that I can't add this kind of script after fetching information using a useEffect hook?

Comment: @MatePaiva You can still do that using `Script`.

Comment: Does this still work in an `/app` router world? I'm loading a head script with this strategy and defer set to false, still doesn't work. I'll continue to test and post an updated answer if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

Julio's answer above does not work in my testing for Next with the `/app` router. I tried every permutation of the `next/script` tag [per their docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/script) to no avail.

It looks like they've deprecated the `defer` attribute on their implementation of `<script>` or maybe it's a bug and doesn't pass through to the page properly. So it's back to good old `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - this did work. Below is my `/src/app/layout.js` file:

```
import Script from 'next/script';

import { Providers } from '~/components/providers';
import { Wrapper } from '~/components/wrapper';
import { cx } from '~/utils';

import '~/styles/index.css';

export default async function Application({ children }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en-US">
      <body>
        <Providers>
          <Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>
        </Providers>
      </body>
      <script
        type="text/javascript"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `https://your-script-here.com`,
        }}
      />
    </html>
  );
}
```