# Adding tag manager to next js, confusing docs

Tags: next.js, google-tag-manager

I am adding tag manager to my next.js site (next version 12.0.4) and the docs here https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script say that I can use next/script in the _document.js file.

When I follow the instructions I then get an error that points me to this page https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-script-in-document-page saying I cannot use next/script in the _document.js page, this page points back to the original page.

I'm confused, what is the correct implementation?

Comment: Next.js version?

Comment: As stated 12.0.4

Comment: Can you post the `_document.js` code so we can try to repro the issue?

Comment: `next/script` components added to `_document` have to use the `beforeInteractive` strategy. For tag managers it's recommended to use the [`afterInteractive`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#afterinteractive) strategy instead, which injects the script on the client-side and for that reason cannot be used in `_document` (use in `_app` instead).

Comment: Check out this npm package on github: https://github.com/XD2Sketch/next-google-tag-manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a dig around I came across this post:
[Next 11 and adding Script tags not working. No scripts are rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058814/next-11-and-adding-script-tags-not-working-no-scripts-are-rendered)

Basically saying scripts where not working, which once I had ignored the warnings and tried in my solution I found also to be the case.

The solution to use next/head in my _app.js seems to work fine.

read the above comment by @juliomalves for the explanation as to why this is to be done in _app.js

```
import Script from "next/script";

    const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
      <>
        <Script
        id="tagmanager-main"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        async
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID}`}
      ></Script>
      <Script
        id="tagmanager-setup"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID}');
          `,
        }}
      />
        {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-​spreading */}
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
    
    export default App;
```

This was my _document.tsx, maybe there was something in there stopping it from working, but I am happy enough with the working solution above.

```
import * as React from 'react';
// eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-document-import-in-page
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import createEmotionServer from '@emotion/server/create-instance';
// import theme from '../../styles/theme';
import createEmotionCache from '../lib/createEmotionCache';
// eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-script-in-document
import Script from 'next/script';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          {/* <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} /> */}
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          />
          <Script
            id="tagman"
            strategy="afterInteractive"
            async
            src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxxx"
          ></Script>
          <Script
            id="tagman-datalayer"
            strategy="afterInteractive"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());
          
                gtag('config', 'G-xxxxx');
              `,
            }}
          />

          <script
            src={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${
              process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPS_API_KEY || ''
            }&libraries=&v=weekly`}
            async
          ></script>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with static-site generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  // You can consider sharing the same emotion cache between all the SSR requests to speed up performance.
  // However, be aware that it can have global side effects.
  const cache = createEmotionCache();
  const { extractCriticalToChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache);

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name, @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      enhanceApp: (App: any) => (props) =>
        <App emotionCache={cache} {...props} />,
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  // This is important. It prevents emotion to render invalid HTML.
  // See https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26561#issuecomment-855286153
  const emotionStyles = extractCriticalToChunks(initialProps.html);
  const emotionStyleTags = emotionStyles.styles.map((style) => (
    <style
      data-emotion={`${style.key} ${style.ids.join(' ')}`}
      key={style.key}
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style.css }}
    />
  ));

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      ...emotionStyleTags,
    ],
  };
};
```