# Google Analytics 4 does not work with Nextjs Script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, next.js

I have built a site with Nextjs. I tried integrating GA to the site. I tried to implement with next/script tag but GA does not show reports, users, pageviews, etc. on the dash board. But if I use normal `script` tag then it works.

Why Google Analytics is not working with `next/script` tag.

GA Code Snippet with `next/script` [not working]

```
<Script
  src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}`}
  strategy="afterInteractive"
  />
  
<Script id="google-analytics-script" strategy="afterInteractive">
        {`
              window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
              function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
              gtag('js', new Date());
              gtag('config', '${process.env.GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}');
        `}
 </Script>
```

**Note**: I have also tried setting ga code inside `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with `next/script` but it still does not work.

GA code snippet with regular `script` tag [working]

```
<script
  async
  src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}`}
 />

 <script
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
   __html: `
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', '${process.env.GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}', { 'send_page_view': true });
            `,
   }}
 />
```

Now my simple question is that why google analytics is not working with next/script?

Comment: Try changing strategy to lazyOnload. Also, in which file you are putting gtag?

Comment: I also tried changing strategy to lazyOnload. But it even did not work. First I put gtag in _document.js then in _app.js.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same exact issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Next.js Script tag cannot be in the head, it needs to be outside it. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68059559/2031033

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem. Upgrade to next 12.2.0 solved it.

I also found this question, but it doesn't work even when the script was moved out of Head component.
[Next 11 and adding Script tags not working. No scripts are rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058814/next-11-and-adding-script-tags-not-working-no-scripts-are-rendered)

Comment: Maybe the fix here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/37894