# How to transform a 3rd party widget to a NextJS component

Tags: next.js, widget

I want to use a trailfork widget in my NextJS app - https://www.trailforks.com/widgets/config/region_info/.

The source code of the widget contains direct DOM manipulation. When imported to a clean html file the widget works as expected.

Widget:

```
<!-- TRAILFORKS WIDGET START -->
<div class="TrailforksRegionInfo" data-w="435px" data-h="150px" data-rid="6253" data-counts="1" data-stats="1" data-title="1" data-activitytype="1"></div>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://es.pinkbike.org/326/sprt/j/trailforks/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var script = document.createElement("script"); script.setAttribute("src", "https://es.pinkbike.org/ttl-86400/sprt/j/trailforks/widget.js"); document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); var widgetCheck = false;
</script>
<!-- TRAILFORKS WIDGET END -->
```

Following: https://www.devtwins.com/blog/how-to-add-a-third-party-script-to-a-nextjs-website I created a component like this, however nothing shows. Also when I search the elements tab for **https://es.pinkbike.org** there are no results suggesting to me that the script was not added via the head element.

My attempt:

```
import Head from "next/head"

export default function RegionInfo() {
    return <div className="h-96 w-96 bg-black">
        <Head>
            <script type="application/javascript" src="https://es.pinkbike.org/326/sprt/j/trailforks/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
    var script = document.createElement("script"); script.setAttribute("src", "https://es.pinkbike.org/ttl-86400/sprt/j/trailforks/widget.js"); document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); var widgetCheck = false;`}}
            />
        </Head>
        <div className="TrailforksRegionInfo" data-w="435px" data-h="150px" data-rid="6253" data-counts="1" data-stats="1" data-title="1" data-activitytype="1"></div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I was not using the NextJS script tag and then followed: [Next 11 and adding Script tags not working. No scripts are rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058814/next-11-and-adding-script-tags-not-working-no-scripts-are-rendered)

```
import Script from "next/script";

export default function RegionInfo() {
    return <div>
            <Script type="application/javascript" src="https://es.pinkbike.org/326/sprt/j/trailforks/iframeResizer.min.js" />
            <Script type="text/javascript" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
    var script = document.createElement("script"); script.setAttribute("src", "https://es.pinkbike.org/ttl-86400/sprt/j/trailforks/widget.js"); document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); var widgetCheck = false;`}} />
        <div className="TrailforksRegionInfo" data-w="435px" data-h="150px" data-rid="6253" data-counts="1" data-stats="1" data-title="1" data-activitytype="1"></div>
    </div>
}
```