# new pics upload to public folder (local - project) not appear (next js project)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[enter image description here][1]I have a problem with my next js project :
In dev mode when upload new pics to public folder and rerender the pics appear but when do this in
build mode (production ) the pics not appear and rerender component stop.

in dev mode
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw9TC.gif

```
 export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
 const session = await getSession({ req: context.req });
 if (!session) {
 return {
  redirect: {
    destination: "/auth",
    permanent: false,
  },
};
} else if (![1, 21].includes(session.user.jobID)) {
return {
  redirect: {
    destination: "/",
    permanent: false,
  },
};
}
const getEmpsFromAPI = await User.find().exec();
const getEntries = await jobs.find().exec();
// const emps = getEmpsFromAPI;
const dataJson1 = JSON.stringify(getEmpsFromAPI);
const dataJson2 = JSON.stringify(getEntries);

return {
props: {
  empss: dataJson1,
  entriess: dataJson2,
  session,
},
};
}
```

Comment: To clarify: you add the images to public folder and then you execute `yarn build` and `yarn start` and the images do not appear?

Comment: no after build and start any pics uploading to a public folder do not appear but it uploads successfully and when I stop-start and restart the system it appears @gazdagergo

Comment: Hmm, could you please add the code that loads the uploaded images? I suspect that you pre-render the page at build time and  then you only serve it statically

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to access files uploaded to the public folder in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289723/1870780)? Files added to the `public` folder at runtime won't be served by Next.js.

Comment: yes this is the only solution to this problem ,I must build another express server to handle new upload pics to next js

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. Only images which are present in the public folder in build-time are served on runtime as static images. The reason of the images are appearing in dev mode is the hot reload (which is practically a re-build) which is triggered by the new image file addition.

I've found a good example from dzino for nextjs image upload. Have a look on that: https://codesandbox.io/s/thyb0

Comment: I got that much but I want to know what will be the fix If I am uploading image using form (input:file) and then I want to display it... Please help me if you have solution for same. Thanks

Comment: You need to use some cdn or server... just not the nextjs public folder, this is not a place for dynamic images. Note: if you wanna serve your images from a third party domain, you have to whitelist the domain in next config.

Answer (score 0):

create a folder called static in your project root directory. From your code you can then reference those files with /static/ URLs:

```js
export default () => <img src="/static/my-image.png" alt="my image" />
```

```sh
/public
    /static
        my-image.png
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54436083

Comment: thanks, Pradip  but my problem is new images uploaded never appear in public folder