# Local img module not found (NextJs 13, Vercel)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm developing nextjs 13 website and my folder structure looks like below.

```
/public
    /icons
        mail.svg
        phone.svg
    /imgs
        img1.png
        img2.png

/src
    /components
    /pages
        /api
        _app.js
        _document.js
        index.js
    /styles
next.config.js
package.json
```

My problem:
in `Vercel`, when I deploy from github to it, I'm facing
`Module not found: can't resolve '../../../../public/icons/mail.svg' in '/vercel/path0/src/components/Home/mycomponent'`
which is working fine in my local.

I've also run `npm run build` to build in my local and have no errors at all.

How I access those assets in my components:
[according to this nextjs [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images)]

```
import Mail from '../../../../public/icons/mail.svg';
```

inside jsx:

```
import Image from 'next/image';

<Image src={Mail} alt="mail" />
```

How can i solve that problem?

Comment: You need to address the images relative to the base path. So it should be `'/icons/mail.svg'`

Comment: If it's in the public folder than your assets are simply accessible by the root path, e.g. `/icons/mail.svg` like what Dulaj said. [As per NextJs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving): "Files inside public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (`/`)."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nextjs public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436021/nextjs-public-folder)

Comment: I don't want to access those like `<Image src="/icons/mail.svg" alt="" />` because I need to explicitly add width and height of those images inside that `next/image` component. (and I have .png, .jpg also).

Comment: The way I'm using is fine for all images in my dev env. Got that error when I deploy to vercel.

Comment: This works: `const Mail = '/icons/mail.svg'`. VScode can't show the preview in front of this line, but it's the solution.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and the only way that made it work was by using 
const Mail = '/icons/mail.svg'.

Answer (score -1):

Fix import:

```js
import Mail from '../../../../icons/mail.svg';
```

without `public`