# NextJs - Where can we add a <script> code?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

In NextJs application, I want to add `<script>` code but not getting where to add and how? I tried by adding it in `.js` file but didn't recognise.

In react, we have `index.html` to add these things, what about in Nextjs app?

Comment: take a look at this [Next.js Loads <script> tags but it doesn't execute them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54080354/4595934)

Comment: @Ravikumar notice that the answer in shared link will execute script only on index page (if the user enters from other path, it wont be executed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To edit the `index.html`, the equivalent in NextJS is the [`_document.js` file](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

> A custom Document is commonly used to augment your application's `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <script>...</script>
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

If you only want to append elements to `<head>` tag (for a specific page), use [`next/head`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head):

```
import Head from 'next/head'

function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <script>....</script>
      </Head>
    </>
  )
}
```