# Snipcart and NextJS installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, shopping-cart, snipcart

I feel like this is driving me crazy, not being able to get Snipcart set up properly and I am not sure how to resolve this. Maybe someone can tell me what I'm missing here?

So I can add the link references in the 'Head' of the '_document' page just fine, but on Snipcart's installation docs, it says to put this script right after the  element, except it throws errors anywhere I put it. Here is the installation script you need to add:

```html
<script>
  window.SnipcartSettings = {
    publicApiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    loadStrategy: "on-user-interaction",
  };

  (()=>{var c,d;(d=(c=window.SnipcartSettings).version)!=null||(c.version="3.0");var s,S;(S=(s=window.SnipcartSettings).timeoutDuration)!=null||(s.timeoutDuration=2750);var l,p;(p=(l=window.SnipcartSettings).domain)!=null||(l.domain="cdn.snipcart.com");var w,u;(u=(w=window.SnipcartSettings).protocol)!=null||(w.protocol="https");var f=window.SnipcartSettings.version.includes("v3.0.0-ci")||window.SnipcartSettings.version!="3.0"&&window.SnipcartSettings.version.localeCompare("3.4.0",void 0,{numeric:!0,sensitivity:"base"})===-1,m=["focus","mouseover","touchmove","scroll","keydown"];window.LoadSnipcart=o;document.readyState==="loading"?document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",r):r();function r(){window.SnipcartSettings.loadStrategy?window.SnipcartSettings.loadStrategy==="on-user-interaction"&&(m.forEach(t=>document.addEventListener(t,o)),setTimeout(o,window.SnipcartSettings.timeoutDuration)):o()}var a=!1;function o(){if(a)return;a=!0;let t=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],e=document.querySelector("#snipcart"),i=document.querySelector(`src[src^="${window.SnipcartSettings.protocol}://${window.SnipcartSettings.domain}"][src$="snipcart.js"]`),n=document.querySelector(`link[href^="${window.SnipcartSettings.protocol}://${window.SnipcartSettings.domain}"][href$="snipcart.css"]`);e||(e=document.createElement("div"),e.id="snipcart",e.setAttribute("hidden","true"),document.body.appendChild(e)),v(e),i||(i=document.createElement("script"),i.src=`${window.SnipcartSettings.protocol}://${window.SnipcartSettings.domain}/themes/v${window.SnipcartSettings.version}/default/snipcart.js`,i.async=!0,t.appendChild(i)),n||(n=document.createElement("link"),n.rel="stylesheet",n.type="text/css",n.href=`${window.SnipcartSettings.protocol}://${window.SnipcartSettings.domain}/themes/v${window.SnipcartSettings.version}/default/snipcart.css`,t.prepend(n)),m.forEach(g=>document.removeEventListener(g,o))}function v(t){!f||(t.dataset.apiKey=window.SnipcartSettings.publicApiKey,window.SnipcartSettings.addProductBehavior&&(t.dataset.configAddProductBehavior=window.SnipcartSettings.addProductBehavior),window.SnipcartSettings.modalStyle&&(t.dataset.configModalStyle=window.SnipcartSettings.modalStyle),window.SnipcartSettings.currency&&(t.dataset.currency=window.SnipcartSettings.currency),window.SnipcartSettings.templatesUrl&&(t.dataset.templatesUrl=window.SnipcartSettings.templatesUrl))}})();
</script>
```

Putting this script anywhere in '_document' throws an error, after doing a bunch of trial and error. I cannot figure out how to get Snipcart working properly with NextJS and documentation on installation alone seems to be hard to find - which means people don't usually have an issue with it, right? Haha. I am losing my mind on this, and it's probably an easy fix I have overlooked somewhere. Any help is appreciated!

This is where the script is located, in '_document':

```html
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";


export default function Document() {
    return (
        <Html>
            <Head>
                ...
            </Head>
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
                
                <script>
          window.SnipcartSettings = {
            publicApiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
            loadStrategy: "on-user-interaction",
          };

          (()=>{var c,d;(d=(c=window.SnipcartSettings)...
                </script>
            </body>
        </Html>
    );
}
```

Comment: What's the error it throws? By the way, you should take a look at [NextJS' docs regarding this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#afterinteractive) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067291/next-js-loads-script-tags-but-it-doesnt-execute-them.

Comment: They look like syntax errors but I am unsure how to resolve them. The first one is on the colon of 'publicApiKey: ', the error is: ''}' expected.ts(1005)'

Comment: I put the script in a separate file, as suggested in the post you shared, and there are no errors in the script, but clicking the 'add to cart' button does not do anything yet. Still trying things out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here:
[NextJS Snipcart Installation - github](https://github.com/colbyfayock/my-space-jelly-gear/blob/main/src/pages/_document.js#L14-L23)

Omit the 3 links. Not needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).