# How to Set Up the Facebook SDK on next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-authentication, facebook-sdk-4.0

I try to implement *Sign in with Facebook* to my app (next.js), which require me to put  tag to my html file, but with next.js is not static page, so I don't have html file.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54080354/13096566) says I should create /public/static/script.js and put my code something like this:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import MyAwesomeComponent from '../components/mycomponent';

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script.js"></script>
    </Head>
    <MyAwesomeComponent />
  </div>
)
```

Is that the way to do it is it a good practice, or I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Have you tried to use [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) ?

Comment: where in the docs does it say to put a script tag in order to implement facebook login? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk